# Crossing from UK to France and back on the same day in the same car but with different drivers

Tags: uk, france, driving, automobiles, english-channel

I am probably going to have to lend my French-registered car to a relative for his trip to the UK. The day he returns to France I am supposed to be driving to the UK myself in the same car.

Both trips were planned independently of each other a long time ago, but nothing has yet been booked for either crossing and it was only recently that my relative realised he would need to use my car.

Ignoring logistical problems like boats being late, etc, is this likely to cause any major problems with the UK Border Agency or other agencies?

Comment: Why should it be a problem? It is two halves of separate trips. Your relative is returning to France after his trip to UK, and the same day you begin a new trip to UK.

Comment: Yes, I agree, I'm just a bit worried that it might make alarm bells ring on various databases. For example if the relative crosses by boat and a few hours later I cross by tunnel.

Comment: That doesn't seem unusual behaviour to me. There could be many French companies whose vehicles cross to UK every day to make deliveries near the channel ports, with fresh produce for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As people expected, I have completed the trip and it was absolutely no problem whatsoever.

Comment: It's great that you bothered to answer your own question rather than leaving the answer hidden in the comments with the item appearing to be one more "unanswered" question.